# Define name for column func.count in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

There are two tables

```
Tbl1 = Table(
    'tbl_1', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False),
    ...other columns
)
```

and

```
Tbl2 = Table(
    'tbl_2', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False),
    ...other columns
)
```

I want to count all data in both tables for one user.

```
q1 = Tbl1.count().where(Tbl1.c.user_id == some_id)
q2 = Tbl2.count().where(Tbl2.c.user_id == some_id)
union = q1.union(q2).alias('uni')
query = sqlalchemy.select([sqlalchemy.func.sum(union.c.tbl_row_count)], from_obj=union)
```

And question is - how to set a column name for union count column, instead of looking thrue the internals? *union.c.tbl_row_count* i saw only in debug mode.

Second try was:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

q1 = sa.select([sa.func.count(Tbl1.c.id).alias('cnt')]).where(Tbl1.c.user_id == some_id)
q2 = sa.select([sa.func.count(Tbl2.c.id).alias('cnt')]).where(Tbl2.c.user_id == some_id)
union = q1.union(q2).alias('uni')
```

But in that case internal name for column was *uni.c.count_1*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Indeed, it is better to be in control of naming in such cases. See code below for code which should produce `SQL` identical to what you have right now:

```
q1 = select([func.count(Tbl1.c.id).label("xxx")]
            ).where(Tbl1.c.user_id == some_id)
q2 = select([func.count(Tbl2.c.id).label("xxx")]
            ).where(Tbl2.c.user_id == some_id)
union = q1.union(q2).alias('uni')
query = select([func.sum(union.c.xxx).label("total_xxx")], from_obj=union)
```

Comment: Yes, it's what i mean - more control over name. My mistake was that i haven't seen that sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement is descendant of sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement, and it has label()